# Check if package available in python3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, python-packaging

I have a project in Python2.7 and want to port it to Python3.6.

I want to build some kind of dependency tree where I can see which package is available in Python3.6. But don't know why how to check it without trying to install it to Python3.6 environment.

For example: `boto-rsync` is not available for Python3.6, but `redis` do.

And I need some advice where to start.

Comment: Even installation wouldn't be enough because code incompatible with Py3 could be hidden deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Use pip freeze in your both python2 and python3 environments and redirect them to a text files to see what all packages are installed.

Example:

```
pip freeze >> python2.txt
```

Click [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) for pip documentation.